# Burn [m-file] or make synonym of [matlab]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I'd suggest do burn the tag [m-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m-file). (currently used 48 times)

As the tag description suggests, it's pretty obsolete:

> Text file used by MATLAB, an application used for mathematical
>   computations. It can store a script, class, or an individual function
>   in the MATLAB language. Use this tag for questions specifically
>   related to coding of m-files or to m-files applications in MATLAB.

**"Coding of m-files"**  means **"Coding in Matlab"** - you can't code in any other file-format. Also **"m-files applications"** are **"Matlab applications"** - I'm not aware of other programming languages using m-files (apart from the highly related open source alternatives **Octave** and **Scilab**, which then also use the same Matlab code and if not, be tagged with the according name). For me it seems quite pointless to have a tag just for a file-format of a programming language, if there is (practically) no other file format.

Making it a tag-synomym for [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) could be an option too, but as anybody posting a question with [m-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m-file) would also use [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab), it is not necessary.

There are nor tags **c-file** or **py-file** for code in C or Python neither. It would be exactly the same issue.

Comment: What about cases such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375269/octave-error-invalid-character ?

Comment: @JonClements well the m-file in this case is just a text-file with the extension .m containing Matlab code. And octave ist just an open source alternative to Matlab to write and execute Matlab-Code stored in m-file. Also, there is no tag "c-file" or "py-file" which would be exactly the same for C or Python.

Comment: @thewaywewalk *[...] you can't code in any other file-format.* MATLAB also has [p-files](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html).

Comment: @Jubobs: fair point, but a very rare case. Would justify the m-file tag, but the p-file tag though.

Comment: I totally agree, this tag adds *no* information to a question, and most times it wont even be directly related to the question. E.g. in the example linked by Jon Clements, the question is in no way related to the fact that the function is located in an m-file (because: of course it is!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[m-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m-file) has been merged into [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab).